# Insert a piece of data into mysql by using gorm

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I want to insert a piece of data into my database(MySQL). However, I failed.

Error 1364: Field 'envelopeId' doesn't have a default value.

I found that some people say that this is because the primary key is of int type and not set to auto-increment, but this is actually a varchar type.

```golang
var envelope Envelope
envelope = Envelope{
    "100000000001",
    1,
    0,
    100,
}
fmt.Println(db.Create(&envelope).Error)
```

Comment: Show the struct definition and the output of `show create table` on the relevant table.   "this is actually a varchar type"   why are you not using an auto incrementing bigint for primary key?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you are trying to insert an `NULL` value into a non-nullable field, and since there is also no default value specified it gives you and error. I assume `"100000000001"` is your primary key, if this is the case, it is set in your struct and you need to check that that field has the `gorm:"column:envelopeId"` tag set. By [convention](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#Column-Name) GORM will use snake case for column names, not camel case like you have in your DB.